# Check if textbox is empty - is there a better way?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if textbox is not empty.

Is there a better (more elegant, simpler) way than:

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(null == txtBox ? null : txtBox.Text)
```

It is worth to note that `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text)` throws `NullReferenceException` if `txtBox` is `null`.

Comment: Why is `textBox` ever null?  And you say you're checking if it's empty, so why not `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` rather than `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`?

Comment: That's already pretty elegant. But if you want a less-visible solution, you'll need to create on yourself. (Like: Create a base form that automatically checks if all the textboxes are filled in).

Comment: @CharlesMager It's dynamically created.

Comment: @CharlesMager I use IsNullOrWhitespace because whitespace is as good as null in my case. I parse input value into number, value 0.0 is allowed only when explicitly given etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really - however, you could make a little extension if it would save you time:

```
public static class TextBoxExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty(this TextBox textBox)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(null == textBox ? null : textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
if(TextBox1.IsEmpty())
{
    ....
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that only with Extension Methods is that you can do a `null.something()` without getting a null reference exception. :)

Comment: @Andrew Not tested but that makes sense. Because Textbox.IsEmpty() actually means TextBoxExtensions.IsEmpty(Textbox) behind the scenes. Make sure to check in the extension method if the passed parameter was null. Like this answer did.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your `txtBox` can be null (I guess it's a dynamically created control), you could do something like this:

```
bool isEmptyOrNull = txtBox == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text)
```

Comment: +1 For guessing that my txtBox is dynamically created control.
But with all the respect but my code is more compact ;-)

Comment: Yours is actually 6 characters longer ;).  This version doesn't bother executing `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` when it knows there's nothing to check and is arguably more readable.

Comment: That was the point of my code, to avoid executing `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` when it's not necessary. Being the line a bit longer is not important per se.
I guess you considered your code more compact because you included my `bool isEmptyOrNull = ` in the comparison. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Actually In the end I included your answer in my extension method :-)